# UITableViewCell -> Style: UITableViewCellStyleValue2 -> change indent

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use the `UITableViewCellStyleValue2`, so I have text on the left and on the right side.
It looks like in the iPhone address book, see screenshot here: 
http://files.zimbra.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/screenshot-2008-06-10-022326-0700-1.png

But how can I change the indent, so the text on the left side will have more space? Is this possible or do I need to create a customized cell?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no property to do that. You'd have to manually modify the frames for both labels.

See this answer for more info:
[How to change the size of the labels on a UITableViewCellStyleValue2 cell? (UITableView iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093007/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-labels-on-a-uitableviewcellstylevalue2-cell-uitab)

Comment: If all you're doing is changing the frame, I'd do it without a customized cell.

Comment: But how can I write this, because I get the warning: `UITableViewController may not respond to layoutSubviews`.I have a `UITableViewController` and my view nib file has a `UITableView`.

Comment: You would implement layoutSubviews if you want to subclass. But first try this in your _cellForRowAtIndexPath_: `CGRect leftFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height); cell.detailTextLabel.frame = leftFrame;` and same thing for the right one.